# Storing multiple values for a single field in a database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

Suppose i have a table with 3 fields

Person_id, Name and address. Now the problem is that a person can have multiple addresses. and the principle of atomic values says that data should be atomic.

So then how am i suppose to store multiple addresses for a single person ?

Comment: ya well i am getting use to the sites functions initially i didn't knew how to approve an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're supposed to create an `ADDRESS` table that has a foreign key linking it to a `PERSON` record, i.e. `PERSON_ID`.  This is the "relational" component of a relational database, and it's why it's more flexible than a flat file (which is like a single table).

Comment: but then what would be the primary key of the address table ?

Comment: `ID` would be the primary key.  `ADDRESS` table would have multiple fields, starting with `ID`, `PERSON_ID`,`STREET`,`CITY`, etc.

Comment: ok and what if the a single address can have have multiple persons ?

Comment: That single address could have multiple records in the ADDRESS table with different PERSON_ID.  BTW, is this homework?

Comment: I would call the primary key Address_Id, rather than id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I think it's a matter of style/preference.  I always give the primary key of a table the name `ID`, and in tables that reference it, I prefix it with the table name.  Prefixing table name in the table itself feels redundant to me.  And this seems to be in keeping with what many popular frameworks default to (I'm thinking of Grails).

Comment: @marc well it is but its a computer parts database not the stuff i am asking. ok but if there are multiple records of the same address with just a different person id wouldn't that be quite redundant. For example what if 2 persons have the same house and there is a field of house color and i change it only in one record and forgot to do it in the other ?

Comment: @SomeBody, you could consider making `ADDRESS` the parent side of the relationship with `PERSON` being the reference, or you could create a bidirectional relationship.  But this discussion is going beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: ya i know its sort of going beyond the original scope just trying to visualize a few problems that might occur in the databse that i have to make.Anyways i have looked in the book and it says that the relationship in this case is many to many and i should consider making a connecting table with a composite key of person_id and address_id. What about this solution ?

Comment: Sure, you could also create a table that serves only to link an ADDRESS with a PERSON record.

Comment: well then i guess i understand it completely now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Small correction: the "relational" part of the database is the tables, not the joins between them. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Relations_or_Tables

Answer (score 1):

Put adresses in a second table, give each adress a "Person ID", so that mutiple rows in the adress-table can referr to on person.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a address type to the address table to identify which type of address it is (Home, Vacation, Office), etc.  Something like: AddType that refers to a list table where more types could be added down the road.